# How to upload a bitmap into firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase

How can we upload a fingerprint Bitmap into the firebase? how can we compare two bitmaps? how can we get the results of the comparison of two bitmaps

Answer (score 2):

Tutorials for uploading images onto Firebase are plenty. For example, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) and [this](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/gestures-animations-flexible-uis/using-the-camera-and-saving-images-to-firebase). Comparing fingerprints, on the other hand, is not easy as comparing two normal bitmaps. A good open source for that is [openCV](http://opencv.org/). You can also take a look at [these algorithms](http://biometrics.mainguet.org/types/fingerprint/fingerprint_algo.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload your Bitmap as image into `Firebase Cloud Storage`. Save bitmap as `file.png` and then upload it to `Firebase Cloud Storage`. Here is [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) to storage documentations.

Easiest way to compare 2 bitmaps - pixel by pixel. You can perform some searching for images comparison. As a result you can take percentage difference in images and treat <10% difference as identical images.

Or you can use new `Firebase Cloud Functions` to compare images using Firebase servers.